# CData for SSIS MongoDB connector to Bulk insert SQL Server DB in cloud

Tags: mongodb, ssis, cdata

I am using a tool for loading/connecting MongoDB data called Cdata for SSIS Mongo Connector. Using this tool I am able to extract the data and download the data to my local machine.

But, when I try to load in a SQL Server staging table it gives me the following error:

> the select data source is on a remote computer.The bulk insert
>   operation can be executed only on the computer where this data source
>   is located.

Is there any work around for copying data to my SQL Server in the cloud & possible replacement for CData as I am using only a 30 day trial period?

Comment: Does the error originate from the CData component or from a native SSIS component? My understanding is that you are not able to perform a Bulk Insert to an Azure SQL instance: http://thecodegarden.net/bulk-insert-azure-sql/ You may be able to turn Batch/Bulk Mode off by editing the properties of the component(s) you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

The below link might be helpful for you to reslove your issue, but you should be aware of Mongo db.
https://arcanecode.com/2014/01/14/importing-mongodb-data-using-ssis-2012/

Comment: Please share some bits of code with little explanation from the link you shared, that would save the time of OP...